# set max rows 4 and columns to be dynamic in RecyclerView GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I want a grid view which adds elements in new row each time when the row count reach 4 it should start adding element in 1st row.

Let say I have 7 items in 1st image and add 2 more elements then it should add first element at last index of 2nd column and second element at 1 index of column 3

Let say I have 11 items in 2nd image and add 2 more elements then it should add first element at last index of 3rd column and second element at 1 index of column 4

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = 
                   new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
            layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: How do we stop from scrolling horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recycleView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```